# Configuring Tensorflow to use all CPU's

Tags: tensorflow

Reading : 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/resources/faq.html it states :

> Does TensorFlow make use of all the devices (GPUs and CPUs) available
>   on my machine?
>
> TensorFlow supports multiple GPUs and CPUs. See the how-to
>   documentation on using GPUs with TensorFlow for details of how
>   TensorFlow assigns operations to devices, and the CIFAR-10 tutorial
>   for an example model that uses multiple GPUs.
>
> Note that TensorFlow only uses GPU devices with a compute capability
>   greater than 3.5.

Does this mean Tensorflow can automatically make use of all CPU's on given machine or does it ned to be explicitly configured ?

Comment: it will use all the available CPUs

Comment: @fabrizioM thanks but where is this referenced in the docs ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CPUs are used via a "device" which is just a threadpool. You can control the number of threads if you feel like you need more:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
  intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_THREADS))
```

Comment: Does one have to worry about the limitation of Python's GIL to this application? Isn't threading with CPUs not useful because of GIL?

Comment: This is the number of threads the internal C++ runtime uses, which is independent from python.

Comment: funny. for some reason setting this to 1 greatly improved my training speed, lol!

Comment: Multithreading does not necessarily guarantee better performance. It actually slow you down if the task is not suitable to form a queue.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: @Hadij - they removed Session in TF2.0... Not sure how to do it in TF2 yet..